# Merging rows in a dataframe pandas by comparing time and duration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What is the most efficient way to merge rows (millions of records) within the same dataframe?

Input/Output columns [id, startTime(secs), duration(secs)]

For a given id, if the startTime + duration equals startTime of the next row (for the same id), then, the output dataframe should contain the id and the min startTime row and sum of all the duration.

Note: Even if the sum of startTime + duration differs by 1 sec, it should not be combined to the existing row and should be displayed as a separate row.

[Input DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI99M.png)

```
id  startTime(secs) duration(secs)
1   65760   60
1   65820   780
1   66600   1740
1   68340   60
1   68401   120
1   68521   60
1   69000   120
2   67899   60
3   56000   780
3   56780   60
```

[Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/127Uk.png)

```
id  startTime(secs) duration(secs)
1   65760   2640
1   68401   180
1   69000   120
2   67899   60
3   56000   840
```

In the above example, for the first four rows,

row1 -> id =1, startTime + duration = 65760 + 60 = 65820 ==> row2 (startTime),
hence row1 will have startTime as 65760 and duration as 840 (60 + 780).

New row1 with respect to row3, row1 startTime 65760 + 860 (newly computed duration) = 66600 ==> row3's startTime. Now row1 will become 1, 65760, 2580 [id, startTime(secs), duration(secs)].

Again, New row1 with respect to row4, row1 startTime 65760 + 2580 (newly computed duration) = 68340 == row4's startTime. Now row1 will become 1, 65760, 2640 [id, startTime(secs), duration(secs)].

Now, New row1 with respect to row5, row1 startTime 65760 + 2640 (newly computed duration) = 68400 != row5's startTime. Row1 will be 1, 65760, 2640 [id, startTime(secs), duration(secs)] and row5 will be considered as separate row.

Comment: Is it possible that a single row could overlap into the next? I.e. 65760 with a duration of 80 seconds in your first row? Just complicates the logic a bit

Comment: No. It won't. For an id, each row startTime  + duration will be equal or greater than the next one. Also, the startTime is sorted for an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that overlaps only occur at exactly the edges, you can check if the `id` is the same and the stop is the same as the start of the next row to create your grouping variable.

```
df['stop'] = df['startTime(secs)'] + df['duration(secs)']
s = (df.id.ne(df.id.shift()) | df['stop'].shift().ne(df['startTime(secs)'])).cumsum()
df.groupby(s).agg({'id': 'first', 'startTime(secs)': 'min', 'duration(secs)': 'sum'})

#   id  startTime(secs)  duration(secs)
#1   1            65760            2640
#2   1            68401             180
#3   1            69000             120
#4   2            67899              60
#5   3            56000             840
```